# Docker: create Astra Linux image

Tags: docker

Unfortunately, I have to use Astra Linux in my current project. So, I would like to have a docker-image with it.

Have someone already done this job? Or how can I do it by myself?

```
$ docker search astra
NAME                                    DESCRIPTION                                     STARS               OFFICIAL            AUTOMATED
sogimu/astralinux                                                                       2                                       
pgpro/astra-build                                                                       1                                       
pgpro/astra                                                                             1                                       
astra50/astra50                                                                         0                                       
astralengine/aarch64-linux-android                                                      0                                       
astralengine/arm-linux-androideabi                                                      0                                       
astralengine/x86_64-linux-android                                                       0                                       
...                                     
$ docker run -it sogimu/astralinux
Unable to find image 'sogimu/astralinux:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from sogimu/astralinux
08439006c671: Pull complete 
da279d7141af: Pull complete 
bad5eb31b027: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:bb66e83e2402ccc7d74d5b1aee1081bc91310ebbb6b79289963a9b364c7d9d32
Status: Downloaded newer image for sogimu/astralinux:latest bash
root@c28305fc4334:/# uname -a
Linux c28305fc4334 4.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 6 09:33:07 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ubuntu?!

The problem is that the OS doesn't have `dirmngr` package in its repo:

```
# apt-get install debootstrap dirmngr
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Не удалось найти пакет dirmngr
```

Furthermore, there isn't appropriate script in `/usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/*`

I need an advice.